# How do you add two variables containing decimals in python?

Tags: python

I have a script simply

```
print("Do you want item 1? It costs 3.60")
answer = input()
if answer == "yes":
     item1cost = 3.60
else:
     item1cost = 0
print("Do you want item 2? It costs 3.90")
answer = input()
if answer == "yes":
     item2cost = 3.90
else:
     item2cost = 0
print(item1cost+item2cost)
```

I have tried to look at other questions, but they do not answer the question at all xd
Please help quickly.
edit:

Comment: `if int(answer)==1`

Comment: considering both options would be 1, resulting in registering a value for each variable

Comment: im specifically looking for the last line, i want the answer to be 7.50

Comment: Why isn't the answer to the questions `yes` or `no`?

Comment: @Intel_Inside - `input()` returns a string. Cast it to `int` as I suggested and your code will work as expected.

Comment: If you enter `1` you compare the string `"1"` from the input with the number `1`. A string and a number are never equal. You might want to use `if answer == "1":`. ... After your edit: use `if answer == "yes":`.

Comment: It's just an example for now, I need to know how to add two or more variables with decimal values, such as 3.9 etc.

Comment: You add them as you did it: `item1cost+item2cost`. Your problem is that both values are `0` and you seem to expect other values.